# Finite Picard group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, picard-group

Does there exist a connected scheme, smooth, proper, and positive-dimensional over $\mathbb{C}$ with finite Picard group? Note that Picard group [has](https://mathoverflow.net/a/148650/138661) cardinality$>1$. Also note that this [can not happen](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1027136) for projective schemes.

Comment: No, as shown in this https://mathoverflow.net/a/122718/39304 answer any such variety admits a divisor $D$ which intersects some curve $C$ positively. The class of $D$ in the Picard group is cannot be torsion because if $nD$ was linearly equivalent to $0$, the intersection $nD\cdot C=n(D\cdot C)$ would vanish.

Comment: Meta discussion here:  https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4200/flood-of-new-users